# WordPress multiple-submenu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, categories, submenu

What's the best way to make multiply-page menu?
For example Category1 -> Article -> Full article text?
Not dropdown menu.

There's site example: http://fl.jetcode.lv/service.html

There are on page "Услуги" (Services), list with point's (Обслуживание windows, Подключение интернета, Сборка компьютеров, Чистка вирусов, ...)

When i click one of them (for example 'Обслуживание windows'('Maintenance windows')), i need to get page with points of that category like Установка Windows XP /Vista /7 /8 / W.S 2003,2008 (Installing Windows), Установка Linux (Installing Linux). And each Category have their own list of that text. So what's the best way to make that?

By steps:

`1. I'm here: http://fl.jetcode.lv/index.html
 2. I click on 'Обслуживание windows', and go to that page http://fl.jetcode.lv/service.html
 3. Now i see a list with services on that category
 4. Click on 'Полное описание', under 'Установка Windows XP /Vista /7 /8 / W.S 2003,2008'
 5. And get to that page http://fl.jetcode.lv/service_inside.html`

So how i can structure that's menu with WordPress ?

I've created a Posts with first categories (Category1), then i added it to Appearance->Menus, and get that list on page. Now i can manage their content in post, but it will be hard for end-user. So i trying to make list with second-category in post, and stucked. So can somebody please advice how it correctly/better to do ? 
Thanks!

Comment: Your explanation, point and goal are confusing, please reconstruct your question and relay as much info as possible.

Comment: Sorry, i'll rewrite my question.

Comment: I edited my question, hope now it will be easier to understand what i mean.))

Comment: Ok, you know that Categories results are thrown in categories.php right?

Answer (score 1):

To put this simply,

You won't be needed to change anything to header but in `category.php`.

Instead of including the `<section id="menu">` in the header put it on `categories.php` then to the usual get post contents and you are done.

The logic isn't in the menu but the flow of how you call each file/element.

This is the sample structure in `category.php`

```html
    <h1 class="post-title"><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
                
                <!-- Display all posts under specific Category -->
                <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                <hr />
                <div id="category-post">
                    
                    <!-- Display the Post Title -->
                    <h1><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                    
                    <!-- Display the Date & Time of Post -->
                    <p class="post-date">Posted on <span><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></span></p>
                    
                    <!-- Checks if the post has Featured Image, else will load
                         the default thumbnail called post-thumb.jpg.
                         Delete ELSE CLAUSE to remove default thumbnail feature.
                    -->
                    <?php
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                            the_post_thumbnail( add_image_size( 'post-thumbnail'), array( 'class' => "post-thumb" ) ); 
                        }
                        else {
                            echo '<img class="post-thumb wp-post-image" src="'; 
                            echo bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); 
                            echo '/_/img/post-thumb.jpg" />';
                        }
                    ?>
                    
                    <!-- Display the excerpt if specified IF NOT, will display the
                         first 20 words in the actual content.
                         See functions.php for the excerpt lenght setting.
                    -->
                    <div class="category-content">
                        <?php the_excerpt();?>
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- Displays a link to the actual post -->
                    <a class= "category-read" href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">Read</a>
                </div>
                 <?php endwhile; ?>
                
                <!-- Displays the link for NEXT and PREVIOUS entries.
                     By default, only 10 posts per page can be loaded.
                     See [Settings > Reading] in Wordpress Panel to configure
                -->
                <div id='paging'>
                    <?php next_posts_link('« Older Entries ') ?>
                    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                    <?php previous_posts_link(' Newer Entries »') ?>
                </div>
```